# Autoformat XML string/stream programmatically

Tags: c#, xml, autoformatting

I have a valid xml stream and want to write this stream to debug output in an easy readable way.

At the moment I get something like this:

```
<bla><yadda>hello</yadda><yadda>world</yadda></bla>
```

But what I want is this:

```
<bla>
    <yadda>hello</yadda>
    <yadda>world</yadda>
</bla>
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
stream.Position = 0;
byte[] bbb = stream.GetBuffer();
string str = "";
for(int i = 0; i < stream.Length; i++)
{
  byte b = bbb[i];
  str += Convert.ToChar(b).ToString();
}
Debug.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `XDocument` and load the steam

```
XDocument doc= XDocument.Load(stream);

Debug.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
string xml = "<bla><yadda>hello</yadda><yadda>world</yadda></bla>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

OUTPUT

```
<bla>
   <yadda>hello</yadda>
   <yadda>world</yadda>
</bla>
```

Answer (score 1):

another way is to use System.Xml.Linq.XElement:

```
var xel = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse("<bla><yadda>hello</yadda><yadda>world</yadda></bla>");
Console.WriteLine(xel);
```

Answer (score 1):

this works as well:

```
StreamReader strm = new StreamReader(@"D:\\maoh.xml");

while (strm.EndOfStream == false)
{
     Console.WriteLine(strm.ReadLine());
}
```

and gives:

[image]

Comment: dear @NoOne , thank for your edit, but please do not edit the code, just formation. i know it's the same, but still... i write this way for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tidy.Net library for this. It allow you to:

- break-before-br

  indent

  indent-attributes

  indent-spaces

  markup

  punctuation-wrap

  sort-attributes

  split

  tab-size

  vertical-space

  wrap

  wrap-asp

  wrap-attributes

  wrap-jste

  wrap-php

  wrap-script-literals

  wrap-sections

http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html